Playwright test failing on running npx playwright test
I'm new to Playwright and I'm trying to run the default test already present on the Playwright project.
So far, I have tried installing the dependencies on my system using apt (Ubuntu) that are mentioned but still I'm getting the error of missing dependencies.

tests/example.spec.js
// @ts-check
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);
});

test('get started link', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Click the get started link.
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Get started' }).click();

  // Expects page to have a heading with the name of Installation.
  await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Installation' })).toBeVisible();
});

ERROR:
-> npx playwright test

Running 6 tests using 2 workers
  1) [webkit] › example.spec.js:4:1 › has title ────────────────────────────────────────────────────

    Error: browserType.launch: 
    ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
    ║ Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers. ║
    ║ Missing libraries:                                   ║
    ║     libicudata.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicui18n.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicuuc.so.70                                   ║
    ║     libvpx.so.7                                      ║
    ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

  2) [webkit] › example.spec.js:11:1 › get started link ────────────────────────────────────────────

    Error: browserType.launch: 
    ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
    ║ Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers. ║
    ║ Missing libraries:                                   ║
    ║     libicudata.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicui18n.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicuuc.so.70                                   ║
    ║     libvpx.so.7                                      ║
    ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

  2 failed
    [webkit] › example.spec.js:4:1 › has title ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    [webkit] › example.spec.js:11:1 › get started link ─────────────────────────────────────────────
  4 passed (18.3s)

  Serving HTML report at http://localhost:9323. Press Ctrl+C to quit.


what command did you use to install playwright initially?
